# background-image transition when an element hovers

Tags: jquery, css

I have a complex problem with CSS and JQuery.
I set my body's background-color to green and I want to change my background to a image when a user hovers the mouse on a button.
I used JQuery in order to change the backgrond-image but I want it to change the background smoothly(transition).
I used CSS transition but it seems it doesn't work in this case.
Any idea?
Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#icon-contact").hover(function () {
        $("body").toggleClass("body-icon-contact-hover");
    });
}
);
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#icon-album").hover(function () {
        $("body").toggleClass("body-icon-album-hover");
    });
});
```

```css
body{
 background-color:#1bbc9b;
 transition: all 3s ease;
}
.body-icon-contact-hover{
 background-image:url(../img/contact-bg.jpg);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
}
.body-icon-album-hover{
 background-image:url(../img/album-bg.jpg);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="center-container">
             <a class="center-circle" id="icon-contact">
                 <div class="tooltip">
                     Contact US
                     <div class="triangle">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="center-circle" id="icon-logo">
                </a>
                <a class="center-circle" id="icon-album">
                 <div class="tooltip">
                     Album
                     <div class="triangle">
                     </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot transition `background-image`, here's [a full list of properties you can animate](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animation-of-property-types-).

If you don't want to change your JS then the easiest way is to create separate containers for content and background and then transition opacity instead of background-image:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#icon-contact").hover(function () {
        $(".background").toggleClass("body-icon-contact-hover");
    });
}
);
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#icon-album").hover(function () {
        $(".background").toggleClass("body-icon-album-hover");
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.background {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
}

.body-icon-contact-hover{
    opacity: 1;
 background-image:url(http://dummyimage.com/1000x1000/eee/fff&text=this+is+an+image);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
}

.body-icon-album-hover{
    opacity: 1;
 background-image:url(http://dummyimage.com/1000x1000/ddd/fff&text=this+is+an+image-2);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="content">
    <div id="center-container">
    <a class="center-circle" id="icon-contact">
        <div class="tooltip">
            Contact US
            <div class="triangle">
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="center-circle" id="icon-logo">
    </a>
    <a class="center-circle" id="icon-album">
        <div class="tooltip">
            Album
            <div class="triangle">
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bartkarp/rvh17Lua/

Although IMHO you should never animate the whole background (poor UI/UX).

Answer (score 0):

you can also use css a `div` can be added as overlay with `100%` `width` and `height`

```css
a {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: .5s linear;
  z-index: -1;
}
#icon-contact:hover ~ .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  background: url(http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-69737.jpg);
}
#icon-album:hover ~ .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  background: url(http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-79573.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div id="center-container">
  <a class="center-circle" id="icon-contact">
    <div class="tooltip">
      Contact US
      <div class="triangle">
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="center-circle" id="icon-album">
    <div class="tooltip">
      Album
      <div class="triangle">
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```